# How to change the charging chime on MBP (PowerChime.app)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, charging, root

Many people want to disable the charging chime introduced with the USB-c MBP's (and some enable on non-USB-c). I, however, want to change the chime.

Sadly however I can't change anything in "PowerChime.app" even after disabling the SIP (startup CMD+R, terminal > csrutil disable). I also can't "swap" the PowerChime.app app.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact question, Googled it, landed on here and found the answer hours later, lol.

If you're still looking for the answer, or for anyone's future reference -- after disabling SIP and restarting, open terminal and run:

```
sudo mount -uw /
killall Finder
```

... and you're good to go. Just proceed to replace the .aif file in "Powerchime.app". For me, I changed mine to the old iOS charging chime!

Haha